# Warum erfordert das Zeitwort "geraten" den Wenfall?

Tags: difference

Ich habe mehr als einmal in vielen Büchern gelesen und möchte wissen, ob das Verb *geraten* dasselbe wie *bringen* und *kommen* bedeutet? Ist *geraten* ein gehobenes Tuwort?

> Der Ring ist in (die) Vergangenheit geraten.

Kann man auch wie folgt schreiben?

> Der Ring hat zur Vergangenheit gebracht.
>   Der Ring ist in die Vergangenheit gekommen.

Comment: Der Akkusativ ist eine wohin-Angabe und wohin-Angaben stehen normalerweise im Akk.: Ich gehe/fahre in die Stadt.

Comment: Deine Beispiele sind unverständlich.

Comment: Äh, was? _Der Ring ist in Vergangenheit geraten_ ist syntaktisch korrekt, ergibt aber keinen Sinn. Ist vielleicht _Verlust_ gemeint?

Comment: Der Ring hat etwas/jmd. (zur => in die) Vergangenheit gebracht? Sich selbst (wie im ersten Beispiel)?

Comment: Also ein Ring für Zeitreisende? Irgendwie glaube ich nicht, dass das gemeint war ...

Comment: (Falsche) Analogie zu _in Vergessenheit geraten_?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Das Verb heißt so viel wie

> wind up in a situation/find oneself in a situation

Das "in" kommt mit Akkusativ, da du am Anfang von "geraten" noch nicht in der Situation bist und am Ende dann schon. Wir haben also eine gerichtete Bewegung, ergo Akkusativ.

Answer (score 0):

[Geraten.](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/geraten)

-->
[1](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/geraten) zufällig/ ohne Absicht an den falschen Ort oder in eine unangenehme Situation kommen

Demnach ja. Kommen würde ein Synonym zu geraten sein.

Die Beispiele sind aber unverständlich.

Der Satz ergibt mehr Sinn: "Der Ring ist in die Vergessenheit geraten." 
Oder: "Der 'Ring ist in die Objektgruppe namens Vergessenheit gekommen."

Geraten ist aber meiner Meinung nach treffender. Weil geraten besser ausdrückt, dass es einfach so passiert ist.